# Getting siblings to work in jquery collapsing menu

Tags: jquery, menu, xss

I put together a quick script for a collapsing menu and used `$(location).attr('pathname')` to match the menu item with the current page and set a class to it.  Only problem seems to be that certain pathnames don't play well with the `.siblings('ul').hide()` part.

I did it this way to avoid having a flash where all menu items close and then the matching menu quickly reopens. But I'm noticing that on pages with **pathnames** like page-number-two and page-number-four, the menu items for those pages don't slide open.  They do, however, get the 'current' class applied.

So, a couple questions.

1. Is it likely the dashes are causing the string to evaluate incorrectly or is it more likely just arbitrarily closing the active menu because of the way I chained it together? P.S. Here's a fiddle where I removed the siblings chain and hid the menus from a standalone call, but because of the nature of the URL, it can't actually work.   http://jsfiddle.net/contendia/ddXBU/
2. As an aside, is there any XSS vulnerability to using the pathname this way? Should I sanitize it, and if so how?

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    // Get the URI path and strip the leading slash
    var path = $(location).attr('pathname').replace(/\//, ""); 
    // Get and append the querystring
    path += $(location).attr('search');  
    // Go up 2 levels (a > li > ul) and open. Hide all others.
    $('#leftmenu a[href="' + path + '"]').addClass('current').parent().parent().slideDown().siblings('ul').hide();

   $('#leftmenu h3').click( 
       function() {
           var $this = $(this);
           $this.next('ul').siblings('ul').slideUp();
           $this.next().slideToggle(300); 
    });
    });



    <div id="leftmenu">
    <h3>First Menu</h3>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="page_number_one">Underscores</a></li>
       <li><a href="page-number-two">Hyphens</a></li>
    </ul>

    <h3>Second Menu</h3>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="page_number_three">Underscores</a></li>
      <li><a href="page-number-four">Hyphens</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
   ```